# PhoneGap Build In App Browser not being loaded

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I have a phonegap application that is working perfectly through the local server on the phonegap development iOS app.

Specifically, a call to

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://subdomain.domain.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

works fine in the dev app, however when pushed to phonegap build and accessed via the app installed via testflight, using Hydration to update easily, the button is entirely unresponsive.

I have a feeling that none of the plugins are being loaded, as the status bar is malfunctioning as well.

Here is the relevant part of the config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
```

I know the insecurity of this, however, changing to the url i am trying to access does not change anything:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
</platform>
```

The button in question:

```
<a href="#" id="signUpButton" class="btn btn-default appButton appAlt"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> OR SIGN UP</a>
```

The javascript relating to this button:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

    deviceReadyDependantFunctions();

    initializeApplication();

});

function deviceReadyDependantFunctions(){

alert('initialised!');

$('#signUpButton').unbind().click(function(){

    console.log('here');

    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://subdomain.domain.com?some=variable', '_blank', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert(event.url); });
    console.log(ref);
});

}
```

Obviously, there's a bunch of debugging in there....

The "initialised" alert fires in all environments.

The `event.url` alert fires in the dev app but not in the test flight, hydrated application.

I have been trying everything I can find to rectify this... The only solution I have found is to use a simple `href="theUrl.com"` and let the system browser load it. Which is not a solution at all... I need to load the url in the app. It's a sign up page and is essential that it can be accessed from the app.

Things I have tried:

Every permeation of whitelisting, although there are varying docs saying that in app browser is/isn't affected by the whitelist plugin.

Using a different version of phonegap (`<preference name="phonegap-version"       value="cli-6.5.0" />`) to no avail.

Checked that the plugins are present in the phonegap build "plugins" tab. They are.

Tried replacing the reference to cordova.js with phonegap.js. This didn't work at all.

The order of loading js files (the above call to inappbrowser is in a seperate js file). No difference.

What am I doing wrong?!

Or is there something weird with the TestFlight/Hydrated Application combination?

You can see the ridiculous commits I have made, as well as the full codebase here:

https://github.com/andycharrington/yfa/commits/master

Any advice would be massively appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have also tried every variation of "_blank", "_self", "_system" in the cordova.InAppBrowser.open function.

Comment: Additionally, I have tried every permeation of the Content Security Policy. It currently is: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: wss: ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`

Comment: have you tried uninstalling the plugins and then reinstalling them sometimes this does make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling the unchanged code with Phone Gap Build this morning seemed to magically fix it. Don't you just love it when that happens? :)